# Has anyone consumed a CNCF CloudEvent from Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, cloudevents

I have published several CNCF CloudEvents onto a Kafka Broker. I am trying to view them directly on the broker using this command:

`kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic flink-test --from-beginning`

I not been able to view any data. I have never had this issue with any other serialization format used. Anyone have any thought?

Answer (score 0):

I think,you should include the key.deserializer and value.deserializer in your command that has been used while send the message to the broker.

Example-

kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic flink-test --from-beginning

--property key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

--property value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer